# Best autoregressive estimator when persistence is higher for levels than changes

Tags: time-series, forecasting, data-transformation, autoregressive, macroeconomics

I'm trying to think of how to forecast unemployment using an autoregressive technique. Obviously the persistence is higher in historical data for unemployment than it is in changes in unemployment. (I am looking to predict just 1 quarter into the future.)

However I'm still not sure what would be a forecasting variable. Should I use unemployment to forecast future unemployment or should I use the change in unemployment?